# mvn archetype:create-from-project -DoutputDirectory

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I'm creating an archetype from a project and I'm running that:

```
mvn archetype:create-from-project -DoutputDirectory=../archetype
```

Maven didn't generate the code in `../archetype`. Does somebody know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the [`outputDirectory`](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/create-from-project-mojo.html#outputDirectory) parameter of `create-from-project` goal does not define a user property. Therefore, `maven-archetype-plugin` is simply ignoring whatever value you set with `-DoutputDirectory` and keeps its default value, which is `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/archetype`.

You should create an improvement request at [their JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE) and maybe submit a patch: it should not be difficult to add a user property for this. [Looking the source code](https://github.com/apache/maven-archetype/blob/maven-archetype-2.4/maven-archetype-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/archetype/mojos/CreateArchetypeFromProjectMojo.java#L210-L211), all that should be needed is to add a `property` attribute to the `@Parameter` annotation.